# CSS Child Absolute Content Overlapping Parent Content

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is relative positioned.  Inside that div I have content and then a tag that is absolute positioned.  The container div expands to fit all of the content, but the absolute div is running over the other content instead of the div expanding to fit both.  The problem arises because the site is responsive and I want the links to line up across multiple divs.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
 width:100%;
  }

.child {
    width:90%;
    margin:15px 0;
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
  }

.child a {
    background: #e16d2a;
    border: 1px solid #e16d2a;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
 bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    Curabitur vel feugiat neque, at molestie sem. Ut maximus blandit eros non cursus. Praesent at hendrerit ante. Phasellus volutpat nisl a ante porttitor consequat. Morbi commodo blandit mi, et dapibus mi cursus at. Sed ultricies at tortor a gravida. Proin dictum eleifend pulvinar. Etiam non nisl vel sapien ornare dignissim ornare eu quam. Maecenas lacinia, dui a aliquam molestie, nisl lorem ornare leo, laoreet ornare turpis neque sed elit. Curabitur ornare mauris id felis sollicitudin, sit amet viverra sem pulvinar. Proin porttitor pretium tortor, in aliquet risus auctor in. Nulla in arcu nec est tincidunt ornare. Donec tempor, tellus quis congue fermentum, massa ligula ultricies ligula, eu lobortis ipsum diam vitae tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus id metus a purus interdum efficitur et id arcu. Morbi turpis erat, efficitur id felis et, eleifend ultricies tortor. 
    <a href="#">Link here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ever-present padding to the bottom of the containing element that accommodates for the absolute positioned elements space.

Also in order to get the links to line up across multiple divs I use the technique of setting them to `display: table-cell` this will make the smaller divs share the height of the tallest div.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
 width:100%;
  }

.child {
    width:90%;
    margin:15px 0;
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }

.child a {
    background: #e16d2a;
    border: 1px solid #e16d2a;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
 bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    Curabitur vel feugiat neque, at molestie sem. Ut maximus blandit eros non cursus. Praesent at hendrerit ante. Phasellus volutpat nisl a ante porttitor consequat. Morbi commodo blandit mi, et dapibus mi cursus at. Sed ultricies at tortor a gravida. Proin dictum eleifend pulvinar. Etiam non nisl vel sapien ornare dignissim ornare eu quam. Maecenas lacinia, dui a aliquam molestie, nisl lorem ornare leo, laoreet ornare turpis neque sed elit. Curabitur ornare mauris id felis sollicitudin, sit amet viverra sem pulvinar. Proin porttitor pretium tortor, in aliquet risus auctor in. Nulla in arcu nec est tincidunt ornare. Donec tempor, tellus quis congue fermentum, massa ligula ultricies ligula, eu lobortis ipsum diam vitae tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus id metus a purus interdum efficitur et id arcu. Morbi turpis erat, efficitur id felis et, eleifend ultricies tortor. 
    <a href="#">Link here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doh!  Thank you and sometimes it takes another set of eyes to find what I missed.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

erase position absolute on child a

```
.child a {
    background: #e16d2a;
    border: 1px solid #e16d2a;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    bottom:10px;
}
```

if you wanna show at the bottom then use display block with a max width

```
.child a {
    background: #e16d2a;
    border: 1px solid #e16d2a;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    max-width: 100px;
    bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this will not work for my needs because of what the rest of the code does.  I appreciate your time.